# How do I open the underwater treasure chest?

Tags: toem

In the Stanhamn area, I came across a spot that lets me go underwater if I have the Diver's Helmet equipped. While underwater I found a treasure chest that does nothing when I interact with it. How do I open the treasure chest?

[image: Underwater treasure chest]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the key from a sleeping pirate on a dock.

Head back to the surface, then take the exit near the photo stand of a farmer. Keep walking until you see a sleeping person in a paper hat by the dock. Wake them up with the horn on your camera then talk to them. They'll tell you about the underwater chest, give you the key, and ask you to return the hat you find inside.

[image: Sleeping pirate]